# Login Page in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am wondering if we can create login page for Subscribers in Marketing Cloud.

I want to get them authenticated before they can update their details.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. It will involve a login page with AMPscript which will do a lookup on the form submit. If successful then it will redirect to the Preferences page. If not then it will go to an Error page.

On the successful redirect you can pass through a query parameter to the Preferences page so this page can check whether or not the subscriber is 'Logged In'. You do a check for the query parameter and update a variable to say "SET loggedIn = 'true'". If 'loggedIn' is set to 'true' then do nothing, but if it's set to 'false' then redirect to the error page.

Comment: This is not the Preference Page. I am talking about the below scenario,

Once the customer registers via registration page, I need to send the customer the username and a temporary password to login to the login page. Once the customer login, he would then be able to update his details.

I am wondering if this is possible in the Marketing Cloud.

Thanks

Comment: Yep it's the same principle, however you're including an initial registration page and a triggered send. You store all the username/passwords in DE's and also a Boolean field to see if they have updated the temporary password. They go from the Registration page > receive Triggered send > go to login with temp password > Lookup confirms user & password relationship > if true then redirect to update details (preferences) page